# Flutter Desktop background jobs

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

if there a way to fetch data from http services in background like a Job in Flutter Desktop(Windows).

something like android has workmanager plugin , is there any thing like that for flutter desktop or any logic to achieve it .

Comment: Desktop applications don't pause when they aren't on the foreground the way mobile apps do, so it's not really clear what your question is. There's no difference in execution between the currently focused desktop application and one in the background.